# Mule object-to-json-transformer: how to exclude nulls?

Tags: mule

Is there a way to instruct Mule object-to-json-transformer component to not include null properties into the JSON produced?

By default it produces something like this for null object properties:

```
"value": null
```

Thank you,

ps. just wanna clarify that I'm looking for a way to configure this in Mule, not by using the classes jackson annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer.

Mule object-to-json transformer is ignoring jackson annotations.

Instead, you need to define a customized object mapper bean like this:

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="Bean" name="NonNullMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
            <spring:property name="SerializationInclusion">
               <spring:value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion">NON_NULL</spring:value>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

and then reference the bean in the transformer like this:

`<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON" mapper-ref="NonNullMapper"/>`

Note, that this approach only works with custom java classes.

Comment: Ah, was hoping I could achieve this with annotations. Could please post a link where you found that the transformer is ignoring jackson annotations?

Comment: Here is the link to the Mulesoft KB for the same question: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Suppressing-null-value-fields-with-mapper-configuration-in-objecttojson-transformer

Answer (score 1):

Goes with this, `@JsonSerialize (include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`, simply place it in its class. The library to import is import `org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize`.

Comment: This should be the best answer here

Comment: This answer is wrong. As I've mentioned in the answer below, the component is ignoring the jackson annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the ObjectMapper that the json transformers use like so:

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
        <spring:bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
            <spring:property name="arguments">
                <spring:list>
                    <spring:value>WRITE_NULL_VALUES</spring:value>
                    <spring:value>false</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="json" >

        ...
        <json:object-to-json-transformer mapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />

    </flow>
```

Or if you are using a Map:

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
        <spring:bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
            <spring:property name="arguments">
                <spring:list>
                    <spring:value>WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES</spring:value>
                    <spring:value>false</spring:value>
                </spring:list>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="json" >

        ...
        <json:object-to-json-transformer mapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />

    </flow>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it's crashing with the following error: "org.mule.api.registry.RegistrationException: More than one object of type class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper registered but only one expected." I'm on API Gateway runtime 2.2.0.

Comment: The the first example just crashing with "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.configure(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)". It doesn't like WRITE_NULL_VALUES parameter